# How to handle jwt refresh token with logout?

Tags: authentication, jwt, logout, refresh-token

I'm new to web. My app uses `jwt` for login.

The login flow is:

1. when user login, issue `access_token`, `refresh_token`. store hashed `RT` in DB.
2. when `AT` expires, throw Unauthorization.
3. user will send `RT`. compare it with `RT` in DB. if matched, issue new `AT`.
4. when user logout, remove tokens from client's cookie, and from DB.

But here's my question.

**possible situation:**
if user does not log out `explicitly`, (e.g. close the browser)
user won't have token but **still RT exists in DB**.

1. if user login, new RT will be stored. can new one and old one **co-exist**?
2. in the situation above (or Q1), **how to get online user** properly?
3. `RT` that was stored will expires. **when to remove it from DB**? should I perform polling on DB?